# Unable to import tensorflow_hub in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, bert-language-model

I'm testing the code given by this BERT tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kLi8u2dJz0. However, I'm stuck while trying to import the packages below:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub    
import tensorflow_text as text
```

The error prompted:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'dnn_logit_fn_builder' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\X\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py)

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code:

```
!pip install tensorflow_text
!pip install tensorflow_hub

import tensorflow_hub as hub    
import tensorflow_text as text
```

Please add below code to your program if it still shows the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.estimator.experimental.dnn_logit_fn_builder
```

This may solve this error. Please let us know if still issue persist.